# MySQL: Get row with highest timestamp with group by of multple values

Tags: mysql

Given the following schema:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| timestamp           | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| col1                | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| col2                | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |                |
.....

+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I can do the following query:

```
SELECT * from report_data GROUP BY concat(host_name, ";", service_description)
```

And I would get one row for each unique col1 and col2 combination. It seems it always returns the first row (i.e lowest id) that has the combination.

However in my dataset, I have multiple rows with unique col1 and col2 combinations, and I want the ones with the highest timestamp. The timestamps might be out of order, that is the record with the highest ID might not necessarily have the highest timestamp.

How would I achieve that?

Sample data:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| id  | timestamp  | col1      | col2                   |
+-----+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| 916 | 1          | val1      | valA                   |
| 915 | 2          | val2      | valB                   |
| 914 | 5          | val1      | valB                   |
| 913 | 4          | val1      | valA                   |
+-----+------------+-----------+------------------------+
```

In the above example I would like to have these rows back (there are two occurrences where col1 and col2 is the same, the one with the highest timestamp is returned)

```
+-----+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| id  | timestamp  | col1      | col2                   |
+-----+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| 915 | 2          | val2      | valB                   |
| 914 | 5          | val1      | valB                   |
| 913 | 4          | val1      | valA                   |
+-----+------------+-----------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Newer versions of mySQL support window functions which would allow us to assign a row number based on timestamp and we keep only row 1.  So what version of mySQL is this?  Older techniques would allow us to select max timestamp group by col1, col2 in a derrived table and then join back to the base table to limit the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supported in most version of mySQL: newer version we could use window/analytical functions to do this...

```
SELECT A.ID, A.timestamp, A.col1, A.col2
FROM report_data A
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(timestamp) TS, col1, col2
            FROM report_Data
            GROUP BY COl1, Col2) B
 on A.timestamp = B.TS
and A.Col1 = B.col1
and A.Col2 = B.Col2
```

With 8.0 + of mySQL

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT A.*, Row_number() over (partition by Col1, col2 order by Timestamp Desc) RN
             FROM report_data)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN report_data B
 on CTE.ID B.ID
WHERE CTE.RN = 1
```

Comment: I couldn't remember if 8.0 supported both analytical and cte's so I had to look it up.

Comment: *"I couldn't remember if 8.0 supported both analytical and cte's so I had to look it up."* No problem iám not going to downvote you based on a wrong statement while the query was correct for MySQL 8..  Also MySQL 8 has become much more (modern) SQL standard compliant supporting CHECK constrants also to give a example, still it misses some features like EXCEPT and INTERSECT.